# Getting error when trying to scrape items from flipkart using python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, web, scrapy

Can you please tell what might be the error in it? I am trying to scrape items from flipkart

```py
import scrapy

class flipkart_scrapy(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'flipkart'
    urls = ['https://www.flipkart.com/televisions/pr?sid=ckf%2Cczl&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DMi&otracker=categorytree&p%5B%5D=facets.serviceability%5B%5D%3Dtrue&p%5B%5D=facets.availability%255B%255D%3DExclude%2BOut%2Bof%2BStock&otracker=nmenu_sub_TVs%20%26%20Appliances_0_Mi']
    base_url = urls[0]
    page_no = 2
    next_page = base_url + '&page=' + str(page_no)

    def parse(self, response):
        for product in response.css("div._2kHMtA"):
            yield {
                'name': product.css("div._4rR01T::text").get(),
                'price': product.css('div._30jeq3._1_WHN1::text').get(),
                'rating': product.css("div._3LWZlK::text").get(),
            }

        if self.next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(self.next_page, callback=self.parse)
            self.page_no += 1
            self.next_page = self.base_url + '&page=' + str(self.page_no)
```

That is the code I'm trying run:
`scrapy crawl flipkart`

Can you please tell what might be the error in it? I am trying to scrape items from `flipkart`
it is not scraping anything

Comment: Is your code even running?  Are you instantiating `flipkart_scrapy` and calling `parse()`?  Have you tried printing out your variables to make sure they contain what you expect?

Comment: yes i have tried and it was working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your spider doesn't do anything because you don't have `start_requests` or `start_urls` defined.

From the scrapy API documentation for `scrapy.Spider`:

> This is the simplest spider, and the one from which every other spider must inherit (including spiders that come bundled with Scrapy, as well as spiders that you write yourself). It doesn’t provide any special functionality. It just provides a default `start_requests()` implementation which sends requests from the `start_urls` spider attribute and calls the spider’s method parse for each of the resulting responses.

All you need to do to fix this would be to change your spiders `urls` attribute to be called `start_urls`.  Or override the `start_requests` method.

For example:

```
class flipkart_scrapy(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'flipkart'
    start_urls = [...]  #   <---- This changes to start_urls
```

Comment: i didn't get it

Comment: Just rename the variable `urls` to `start_urls`! The reasons are well described in the answer.

Comment: @UmairEjaz  I added an example

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76191391/not-able-to-send-keys-in-the-instagram-search-bar?noredirect=1#comment134364829_76191391

kindly answr this too