# Not able to send_keys in the instagram search bar

Tags: python, windows, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web

Not able to send_keys in the instagram search bar. This is code im trying to run. The last line is causing problems.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
mobile_emulation = { "deviceName": "iPhone X" }
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)


service = Service("C:/Users/umair/Desktop/codes/chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

driver.get("https://instagram.com")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

name = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "username")))
name.send_keys("")

password = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "password")))
password.send_keys("")

login = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[3]')))
login.click()
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(), 'Not Now')]")))
element.click()
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(), 'Not Now')]")))
element.click()
search_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[contains(text(), "Search")]')))
search_button.click()
search_button.send_keys("Marvel")
```

the last line is causing error.

i expected that it will add text in the search box

Comment: What is the error? Is the search box being clicked?

Comment: you shouldn't be able to `send_keys()` to a button, you'd need to target an input.

Comment: no the search box is only getting clicked when it is in mobile mode

Comment: search_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@aria-label="Search input"]')))
search_button.click() 
TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 1
----> 1 search_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@aria-label="Search input"]')))
      2 search_button.click()

File c:\Users\umair\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py:95, in WebDriverWait.until(self, method, message)

Comment: search_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,  "//input[@placeholder='Search']")))
search_input.send_keys("#Marvel")
search_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

Also this isn't working

Comment: @Mangohero1 kindly  help

Comment: Sorry I don't have an instagram account so I can't get past the login screen